# sed: replace ip in hosts file, using hostname as pattern

Tags: bash, replace, sed, ip, hosts

I'm learning about sed but it is very difficult to me understand it.

I have adsl with dynamic ip so and i want to put current ip on hosts file.

This following script just tells me the current wan ip address and no more:

```
IP=$(dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com)
echo $IP
```

The result:

```
192.42.7.73
```

So, i have a line on hosts file with the old ip address:

```
190.42.44.22   peep.strudel.com
```

and i want to update host file like this:

```
192.42.7.73    peep.strudel.com
```

How can i do it? I think i can use the hostname as pattern...

The reason of doing this is because my server is a client of my router, so it access the internet thru its gateway and not directly. And postfix always is logging me that "connect from unknown [x.x.x.x]" (where x.x.x.x is my wan ip!) and it can't resolve that ip. I think that maybe if i specify this relating with my fqdn host/domain, on hosts file it will works better.

Thanks
Sergio.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**using sed**

```
sed -r "s/^ *[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+( +peep.strudel.com)/$IP\1/"
```

.
`[0-9]+\.` find all lines that matches 1 or more digits with this  pattern 4 consecutive times then pattern `peep.strudel.com` .The parenthesis around the pattern `peep.strudel.com` save it as `\1` then replace the whole patten with your variable and your new ip.

another approach:instead of saving pattern to a variable named IP, you can execute your command line inside sed command line to get the new IP .

```
   sed -r "s/^ *[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+( +peep.strudel.com)/$(dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com)\1/"
```

**using gawk**

```
gawk -v IP=$IP '/ *[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+( +peep.strudel.com).*/{print gensub(/ *[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+( +peep.strudel.com)/,IP"\\1","g")}'
```

Comment: thanks, i used your second example (all in 1 command line), added -i parameter to sed for saving the file, as Avinash Raj and Tiago suggested. It works :) (note: i added more spaces before (     +peep.strudel.com), matching the editing of original post)

Comment: great! :D.I catered for the spaces in my command line  using this piece of code " +" after peep.strudel.com

Comment: I +1 this question so that you can reach 15 rep to vote!

Answer (score 19):

You can use a simple shell script:

```
#! /bin/bash

IP=$(dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com)

HOST="peep.strudel.com"

sed -i "/$HOST/ s/.*/$IP\t$HOST/g" /etc/hosts
```

**Explanation:**

`sed -i "/$HOST/ s/.*/$IP\t$HOST/g" /etc/hosts` means in the line which contains `$HOST` replace everything `.*` by `$IP` tab `$HOST`.

Comment: thanks Tiago, i like your solution, very simple and clear to understand.

Comment: One thing i found is `dig` always returns a zero exit code so could mess up your hosts file. Excellent use of `sed` should have been accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

You need to include the sed code inside double quotes so that the used variable got expanded.

```
sed "s/\b\([0-9]\{1,3\}\.\)\{1,3\}[0-9]\{1,3\}\b/$IP/g" file
```

Add `-i` parameter to save the changes made. In basic sed `\(..\)` called capturing group. `\{min,max\}` called range quantifier.

**Example:**

```
$ IP='192.42.7.73'
$ echo '190.42.44.22   peep.strudel.com' | sed "s/\b\([0-9]\{1,3\}\.\)\{1,3\}[0-9]\{1,3\}\b/$IP/g"
192.42.7.73   peep.strudel.com
```

Comment: [Accept anyone of the answers here which helped you the most.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)